# Make the last row have more columns but span the same width as previous rows

Tags: html, css, html-table

There is the following html code -

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(201, 195, 235);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 5px solid rgb(30, 32, 194);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: rgb(201, 195, 235);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 400px;
}

figure {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

img {
  visibility: visible;
}


/* programmer defined class section */

.button {
  background-color: rgb(201, 195, 235);
  border: none;
  color: rgb(30, 32, 194);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>My Hobbies And Pastimes</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>Walking at Long Lake</li>
    <li>Sharing Good Food</li>
    <li>Attempting to Invent Something New</li>
  </ol>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">My Hobbies and Pastimes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ranking</td>
      <td>picture ON/OFF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <input class="button" type="button" value="Long Lake" id="a1" onclick="toggle(this.id)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <input class="button" type="button" value="Sharing Food" id="a1" onclick="toggle(this.id)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>
        <input class="button" type="button" value="Inventing" id="a3" onclick="toggle(this.id)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <img id="image-a1" src="gt.jpg" alt="Ford GT 2004" width="300" height="168" />
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <img id="image-a2" src="gt.jpg" alt="Ford GT 2004" width="300" height="168" />
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <img id="image-a3" src="gt.jpg" alt="Ford GT 2004" width="300" height="168" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

This is appearing like -

[image: HTML page appearance]

I am creating a simple HTML page with tables. And the last row has multiple columns.

The initial rows displays the numbering and each row has 2 columns. There are three choices specified in the first three columns and each of them refers to an image in the last row.

The last row has 3 images. The other row has two columns. I want the last row of images to span only two columns in total. How do I achieve that?

Comment: [css-file](https://easyupload.io/2o2rvp)  - this contains the css file for this html

Answer (score 1):

You can operate on the *colspan* attribute:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(201, 195, 235);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 5px solid rgb(30, 32, 194);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: rgb(201, 195, 235);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 400px;
}

figure {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

img {
  visibility: visible;
}


/* programmer defined class section */

.button {
  background-color: rgb(201, 195, 235);
  border: none;
  color: rgb(30, 32, 194);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>My Hobbies And Pastimes</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>Walking at Long Lake</li>
    <li>Sharing Good Food</li>
    <li>Attempting to Invent Something New</li>
  </ol>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">My Hobbies and Pastimes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">ranking</td>
      <td colspan="3">picture ON/OFF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">1</td>
      <td colspan="3">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="Long Lake" id="a1" onclick="toggle(this.id)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">2</td>
      <td colspan="3">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="Sharing Food" id="a1" onclick="toggle(this.id)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">3</td>
      <td colspan="3">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="Inventing" id="a3" onclick="toggle(this.id)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <img id="image-a1" src="gt.jpg" alt="Ford GT 2004" width="300" height="168" />
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <img id="image-a2" src="gt.jpg" alt="Ford GT 2004" width="300" height="168" />
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <img id="image-a3" src="gt.jpg" alt="Ford GT 2004" width="300" height="168" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

But it would be more correct to add a nested table:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(201, 195, 235);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 5px solid rgb(30, 32, 194);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: rgb(201, 195, 235);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 400px;
}

figure {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

img {
  visibility: visible;
}


/* programmer defined class section */

.button {
  background-color: rgb(201, 195, 235);
  border: none;
  color: rgb(30, 32, 194);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>My Hobbies And Pastimes</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>Walking at Long Lake</li>
    <li>Sharing Good Food</li>
    <li>Attempting to Invent Something New</li>
  </ol>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">My Hobbies and Pastimes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ranking</td>
      <td>picture ON/OFF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <input class="button" type="button" value="Long Lake" id="a1" onclick="toggle(this.id)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <input class="button" type="button" value="Sharing Food" id="a1" onclick="toggle(this.id)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>
        <input class="button" type="button" value="Inventing" id="a3" onclick="toggle(this.id)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img id="image-a1" src="gt.jpg" alt="Ford GT 2004" width="300" height="168" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <img id="image-a2" src="gt.jpg" alt="Ford GT 2004" width="300" height="168" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <img id="image-a3" src="gt.jpg" alt="Ford GT 2004" width="300" height="168" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```